# Помогите понять)

Tags: пунктуация

"Ленивый - значит умный?" или "Ленивый, значит умный?" А может тут вообще знак не нужен.
Объясните подробно, с примерами, пожалуйста)

Comment: Желателен контекст.

Answer (score 2):

***Ленивый — значит, умный?***

Слово *значит*, если оно синонимично словам *следовательно, стало быть*, является вводным и выделяется запятыми: *Солнечные пятна были на полу, потом перешли на прилавок, на стену и совсем исчезли; значит, солнце уже склонилось за полдень (Ч.); Родятся люди, женятся, умирают; значит, так нужно, значит, хорошо (Остр.); Так, значит, вы сегодня не можете прийти?; Сообщение срочное, а значит, важное.*

Если слово *значит* близко по смыслу к слову *означает*, то пунктуация зависит от места, занимаемого им в предложении:

а) в положении между подлежащим и сказуемым слово *значит* служит средством связи главных членов предложения, перед ним ставится тире, а после него не ставится никакого знака: *Бороться — значит победить*;

б) в других случаях *значит* никакими знаками препинания не выделяется: *Человек значит неизмеримо больше, чем принято думать о нём (М. Г.); Если он говорит, что сделал хорошо, это и значит хорошо; Когда просишь прощения, это значит, что чувствуешь свою вину.*

Если слово *значит* находится между придаточной и главной частями сложноподчиненного предложения и играет роль структурного элемента предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: *Если наступит весна, значит, будет тепло; Раз так упорно отстаивает свои взгляды, значит, чувствует свою правоту.*

Если слово *значит* находится между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: *Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, значит, пеняйте на самого себя.*

Источник: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

Comment: А если предложение утвердительное, то запятая не нужна: "Ленивый - значит умный"
Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Но "ленивый" не означает "умный". Так же нельзя сказать. Знак в конце роли не играет. Да и в правилах о вводных словах нет такого.

Comment: Если спрашивают о значении слова, то будет так: *"Ленивый" значит "умный"?*